# Config.yml configuration when creating a PoS private GETH blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum, configuration, private-ethereum

I'm creating a private blockchain from here: https://docs.prylabs.network/docs/advanced/proof-of-stake-devnet.

The config.yml have this content:

```
CONFIG_NAME: interop
PRESET_BASE: interop

# Genesis
GENESIS_FORK_VERSION: 0x20000089

# Altair
ALTAIR_FORK_EPOCH: 0
ALTAIR_FORK_VERSION: 0x20000090

# Merge
BELLATRIX_FORK_EPOCH: 0
BELLATRIX_FORK_VERSION: 0x20000091
TERMINAL_TOTAL_DIFFICULTY: 0

CAPELLA_FORK_EPOCH: 2
CAPELLA_FORK_VERSION: 0x20000092

# Time parameters
SECONDS_PER_SLOT: 12
SLOTS_PER_EPOCH: 6

# Deposit contract
DEPOSIT_CONTRACT_ADDRESS: 0x4242424242424242424242424242424242424242
```

What `CONFIG_NAME` and `PRESET_NAME` means? Can I change this to what I like? If so, what I must put here and where it affects?

Where can I find docs to this file?